# Simplest way to make a global, auto-incrementing number in mysql

Tags: mysql, global-variables, auto-increment

I essentially want to make a 'global variable' in my mysql database.

So I have a table with two fields:

```
ID
GlobalNumber
```

And I'm doing this travesty:

```
UPDATE that_table SET GlobalNumber=GlobalNumber+1 WHERE ID=whatever            
SELECT GlobalNumber FROM that_table WHERE ID=whatever;
```

But I'm SURE there's a way to do that with a single statement.  Anything I try just gives me a syntax error.

How can I do this whole operation in one line?

Comment: What should be your desired output?

Comment: First fetch, I get GlobalNumber=0, second fetch, I get GlobalNumber=1, third fetch, GlobalNumber=2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` and `select` statement cannot be run together.

Both `update` and `select` statements are two different types of DML (Data Manipulation Language) and cannot be combined together.

However you can selectively update a few tuples where you can use a nested query.

Something like this:

```
update that_table
set global_variable = global_variable + 1
where ID IN(Select ID from another_table);
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of nested query you're talking about?

Comment: Thanks... it's not QUITE the solution I was looking for, but I'll mark it as the answer since I think it's the closest I can get, and I'll fiddle around with it now that I have some idea of syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql's `last_insert_id()` like this:

```
UPDATE that_table SET GlobalNumber = last_insert_id(GlobalNumber+1) WHERE ID=whatever
```

And then in the library that you're using to connect to mysql there's usually some function like `last_id` that will return the value that was set by `last_insert_id(expr)`

Or if you just want to use that GlobalNumber in the next query, you can set a variable while doing the update like this:

```
UPDATE that_table SET GlobalNumber = @num := GlobalNumber+1 WHERE ID=whatever
```

Then use `@num` where relevant in subsequent queries of the same connection.